# Should snmpIfHCInUcastPkts include packets bigger than 1522 bytes?

Tags: ethernet, snmp, bridge

Packets bigger than 1522 bytes (as counted by Spirent Test Center) are being forwarded (bridged) but not counted in the following hardware counters on an Open Network Linux device:

- ifHCInUcastPkts
- ifHCInMcastPkts
- ifHCInBcastPkts

I can't find anything in any of the following documents that excludes large frames from these counters in the following documents:

- 802.3.1 - Management Information Base (MIB) Definitions for Ethernet
- rfc-1643 - Definitions of Managed Objects for the Ethernet-like Interface Types
- rfc-2233 - The Interfaces Group MIB using SMIv2
- rfc-2863 - The Interfaces Group MIB

The following counters are incremented for these frames:

- snmpDot1dTpPortInFrames
- snmpEtherStatsOversizePkts
- etherStatsPkts
- snmpDot1dTpPortOutFrames

There are also some nonstandard counters capturing the above per direction, but none that separate bcast/ucast/mcast.

Am I missing something, or are the counters not working as we'd normally expect?

Comment: My experience suggests that behavior is different from traditional standalone routers & switches e.g. Cisco/Juniper.  I agree with you, the counters are most likely incorrect.  What happens with the **IfHcInOctets** counter; does that also ignore jumbos?

Comment: Unfortunately, your device is off-topic here. You could try to ask about it on [su].

Comment: @RonMaupin This is definitely not a question for SuperUser.  This is a carrier-grade device for 5G deployments.  Please help me understand what's out of scope here.

Comment: You say it is a Linux device, but that is off-topic here. What a host OS implementation does or does not do is off-topic here. You could try to ask on [su], [unix.se], [sf], etc. that deal with host OSes.

Comment: @RonMaupin Actually it's not about a host OS implementation.  I guess I should have left Open Network Linux out of the question.  This is an SNMP question, which I thought might be applicable to this forum.  It's definitely not germane to SuperUser or Unix & Linux, but might be applicable to ServerFault.  Thanks.

Comment: It is a question about a host OS-specific SNMP implementation Protocols that are on topic (at or below OSI layer-4), such as TCP, are not on-topic for a host OS specific implementation.

Comment: @JeffWheeler Sorry I forgot to answer your question right away: they are counted in IfHcInOctets.  In any case, IMHO unless the packets exceed the port MTU, they should be counted.

Comment: @RonMaupin, this has nothing to do with OS implementation.  But it has more to do with network management than network design.  Evidently the tools for monitoring networks to see if they're behaving as designed are not applicable to "network engineering."

Comment: "_are the counters not working as we'd normally expect?_" That is OS implementation-specific.

Comment: No, it's an SNMP question.  What do the standards mean?  Furthermore, the OS software is not involved in any way.  Not in any way.  It was just my way of saying "a commercial grade whitebox device and I don't want to identify the specific implementation."  Would the question have been relevant were it a Cisco router?

Comment: As has been noted on other questions here, the counters (even their existence) varies by vendor, device, and OS. For example, depending on the OS version Cisco devices may have counters that are 32-bit numbers, but those can quickly top out in modern networking, so the counters in other Cisco devices and OSes use 64-bit numbers. None of that is up to the SNMP protocol, it is up to the OS implementation.

Comment: "_a commercial grade whitebox device_" That is most likely off-topic here. We would need to know the vendor and OS. Unfortunately, the Linux Foundation does not offer optional, paid support, which is a requirement here.

Comment: The question was about the standards.

Comment: In any case, the box above explains that if you object to the question closure, you can take your objection to [meta] to let the community decide. (by the way, there have been no reopen votes on your question.)

Comment: The question was about the counters, and there is not actually a standard for that.

Comment: 802.3.1 rfc-1643 rfc-2233 rfc-2863

Comment: The IETF sets the SNMP standards: [RFC 1157](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1157) (SNMP), [RFC 3416](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3416) (SNMPv2), and [RFC3413](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3413) (SNMP Applications), and others. The standards leave the actual data up to the vendors. The standards explain how to form the messages, but what what information and messages a device supports are completely up to the vendor of the device. Also, if there is a bug in the vendor's implementation, that is a vendor-specific problem as you suspect, and nothing to do with the standard.

Comment: RFC 1634 is obsolete, and RFC 2863 is a draft. RFC 2863 explains: "_The exact use and semantics of many objects in this MIB are open to some interpretation.  This is a result of the generic nature of this MIB. It is not always possible to come up with specific, unambiguous, text that covers all cases and yet preserves the generic nature of the MIB. Therefore, it is incumbent upon a media-specific MIB designer to, wherever necessary, clarify the use of the objects in this MIB with respect to the media-specific MIB._" The vendor creates the MIB and its implementation.